# Hide/Unhide action bar items in condition

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

In my Activity I have an three icons in Action bar (search - add - count), I want when variable `hideIcon` is `true` to hide these icons.

The following is my code.

MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        // search action
        return true;

    case R.id.action_add_tip:

        return true;

    case R.id.action_count_tip:

        return true;

    case android.R.id.home:

        return true;

    default:

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

menu.activity_main_actions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- Search  -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/header_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>


<!-- Add Tip -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_add_tip"
      android:icon="@drawable/header_add"
      android:title="@string/action_add_tip"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<!-- Count Tips -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_count_tip"
      android:icon="@drawable/header_count"
      android:title="@string/action_count_tip"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

How can I hide them `if(hideIcon)` is `true` ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//anywhere in your code

hideIcon = HIDE_MENU; // setting state

invalidateOptionsMenu(); // now onCreateOptionsMenu(...) is called again




 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // inflate menu from xml
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);

    if (hideIcon)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++)
            menu.getItem(i).setVisible(false);
    }
}
```